# What is the standard binary search tree structure to use in Scala?

Tags: scala, binary-search-tree, avl-tree, red-black-tree

What is the standard balanced binary search tree implementation one should use in Scala 2.10.x? I am looking around and it seems that `AVLTree` was removed and [`RedBlack`](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/index.html#scala.collection.immutable.RedBlack) is deprecated with a message `(Since version 2.10.0) use TreeMap or TreeSet instead`. However, `TreeMap` and `TreeSet` do not provide the functionality I need because I need to be able to traverse the tree and build a more complex data structure based on this.

Is there any new class that provides the plain balanced binary tree functionality that is not deprecated?

Comment: Are you looking for a mutable or immutable structure?

Comment: Well anything that works well at this point... immutable would be nice

Comment: Why aren't you able to traverse?

Comment: Scala TreeMap and TreeSets are implemented using a red-black tree source code of which is available at https://github.com/scala/scala/blob/2.11.x/src/library/scala/collection/immutable/RedBlackTree.scala.

Answer (score 6):

Trees are fundamental to functional programming and scala, and depending on the complexity of your requirement it wouldn't be a bad idea to roll your own BTree with whatever linkage type and traversal methods fit.

As a general model it could look something like this:

```
trait BSTree[+A] {
  def value: Option[A] = this match {
    case n: Node[A] => Some(n.v)
    case l: Leaf[A] => Some(l.v)
    case Empty      => None
  }

  def left: Option[BSTree[A]] = this match {
    case n: Node[A] => Some(n.l)
    case l: Leaf[A] => None
    case Empty      => None
  }

  def right: Option[BSTree[A]] = this match {
    case n: Node[A] => Some(n.r)
    case l: Leaf[A] => None
    case Empty      => None
  }
}

case class Node[A](v: A, l: BSTree[A], r: BSTree[A]) extends BSTree[A]
case class Leaf[A](v: A) extends BSTree[A]
case object Empty extends BSTree[Nothing]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try this home-made version of binary search trees:

https://github.com/melvic-ybanez/scala-bst

As far as I'm concerned, I am using HashSet which sort the data by key very efficiently when they are immutable.